# -bash: /Users/[me]/.rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, command-line

I was in a directory where I had a ~ and I went to remove it by doing

rm -f ~

for which it said it was a directory. So I made the really silly move of doing

rm -rf ~

and suddenly I get the error

```
-bash: /Users/brent/.rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory
```

See out put

```
cd ..
-bash: /Users/brent/.rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/brent/.rvm/scripts/hook: No such file or directory
```

Can I restore these?

Comment: nope, njet, no, non, nee,  rm-rf  is fatal :)

Comment: Do you have a backup? If not, and you need any of the files from your home directory, SHUT THE COMPUTER DOWN IMMEDIATELY, then use some other computer to research data recovery options.

Comment: I stopped the rm quickly and fortunately I didn't do it as sudo. Looks like I just lost my bash folder